# Selecting Data between sheets to Write a Vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a data in sheet(Sales Data) form Cells B7:B207 and I'm trying to write a vba code for using data to generate Vlookup function in sheet(Salesmen Info). But I failed to generate the VBA Code. Please advise how would I generate the VLookup in (Salesmen Info).

Answer (score 1):

you could just [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) *outside* of VBA with a standard function

`=vlookup(A1,"Sales Data"!$B$7:$B$207,1,false)`

If your VBA is failing, make sure you reference the sheet "sales data" in quotation marks whenever you call it. **What's your current VBA code**?

Additionally, why are you trying to `vlookup` a single column (B). You need your range to be at least 2 columns so it can find the data in B and return the data from C

Answer (score 0):

I like `applciation.vlookup`:

```
arr = application.vlookup(A1,"Sales Data"!$B$7:$B$207,1,false)
```

then, this should work (typing without excel handy so it might not!):

```
for i = 0 to ubound(arr,0)
    for j = 0 to ubound(arr,1)
        debug.print arr(i,j)
    next
next
```

(Press Ctrl+J to see the immediate window and see your output)

or maybe you want it in a sheet?

```
dim rng as range
set rng = range("A1")

for i = 0 to ubound(arr,0)
    for j = 0 to ubound(arr,1)
        rng.offset(i,j).value = arr(i,j)
    next
next
```